# How do I force the rank function to assign a different value to rows of equal rank?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my data base similar to this one

```
ID    Year    Quarter    .....
1     2000    3
2     2002    4     
1     2003    3
1     2000    3
```

The key to the data base is a combination of ID, year, and quarter. I need to grab the most recent entry for each ID, so I used a rank function like this one:

```
select ID
from
(
select ID, Year, Quarter
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Year + Quarter) as rank
from myTable
) tmp
where rank = 1
```

It is possible for there to be an entry in the data base that has the same ID, year, and quarter. I need to be able to choose one of them an none of the others. I don't particularly care which one, just not more than one. I have been reading through the MSDN pages and I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I tried 'DENSE_RANK()', it still assigns '1' to both rows of equal value.

Comment: My bad, totally spaced that you were trying to break ties. In that case follow what A said and use **ROW_NUMBER()**. If you want the most recent value for each id then you'll have to use `ORDER BY Year DESC, Quarter DESC`

Comment: Thanks! This worked great Select *
from(
select *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY year,  quarter) as rank
from mytable
) temp
where rank = 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three basic options - in this case, as others noted, you should use `Row_number()`.

```
Value  Row_Number  Rank  Dense_Rank
A      1           1     1
A      2           1     1
B      3           3     2
D      4           4     3
E      5           5     4
```

Basically, `Row_number` assigns rows one number, and does not duplicate or skip values (unless you are using a partition).  `Rank` allows ties, and skips values if there was a tie for the previous value.  `Dense_Rank` allows ties, and does not skip values.

Comment: This is a very good summary of the differences among these three functions. I know you can derive the same from the manual, but what I particularly like here is your conciseness, good job.